# Set on firebase and then set firebase claims

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-authentication

So i working with firebase auth and database in order to set new user to data base, if set successful i want to set claims for that user. 
So it means i have a promise within a promise:

```
function setUser(user){
// no need for the database code before this, but userRef is set properly 
return userRef.set(user)
  .then(succ => {
    return firebase.firebase.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.key, {admin: true})
    .then(() => {
      console.log("setting claims")
      return true;
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return err
  })
}
```

calling function:

```
app.post("/register_user",jsonParser,async (req, res) => {
 var user = req.body.user;
 let result =  await fireBase.setUser(user);
 res.send(result);
```

})

What happens is that i get the set on the database but claims are not set nor i can i see the log. I know its a js question and not firebase one. I tried many different ways (with await) but non worked.

Comment: How did you determine that the claim is not set?  If it's that the `admin` role doesn't immediately show up in client side code or security rules after setting it, keep in mind that it may take up to an hour for the client to get the new roles, so you'll have to wait for that long, or force the client to refresh the ID token for the user (by calling `user.getIdToken(true)`).

Comment: I also added a console.log() before the return true of the setClaims call just to make sure it actually working. but it never prints.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to reflect the change, and add what specific log you see and which one you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase.firebase` does not seem correct. You need to be using the `admin` object which can be initialised using `const admin = require('firebase-admin');` This is not part of the `firebase` db sdk, but the `admin` one. You can also use the `userRef.uid` as that gives you the id of the document of the user, if that is what you want, else use your `user.key`

```
return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRef.uid, {
                            admin: true
                        }).then(() => {
                            //on success
                        });
```